# How to add an html `class` tag to component element?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a class to the component element itself.

Let's say I have this component:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-preview" constructor="PreviewComponent" extends="div" class="preview">
      <template>
        <div class="preview">

        </div>
      </template>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I would like to be able to remove the `<div class="preview">` element inside, since I already have the wrapping `x-preview` div. Simply setting `class="preview"` on the `<element>` doesn't work.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options that I am aware of:

1) Assign the class wherever you use it:

```
<div is="x-preview" class="preview"></div>
```

The problem with this method is that if you change the class name, you will have to change it anywhere the component is used.

2) Use the inserted lifecycle method to add the class to the root element:

```dart
void inserted() {
  getShadowRoot('x-preview').attributes['class'] = 'preview';
}
```

inserted() will be called whenever the component is added to the DOM. getShadowRoot() will fetch the root element of the component and then set the class to 'preview'. The advantage of this method is you only change the class in one location.

Comment: :( I was afraid that this was the only answer. Thanks anyway!